# Whether someone has done a user defined version of Blinn-Phong (not Blinn and not Phong separately) reflection model in the node editor?

Tags: materials, node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine, shaders

Actually, I am interested in working with Blinn-Phong reflection model in my rendering process, but unfortunately, there is no such a reflection model in Blender.

(Yes, It has Blinn and Phong reflection models separately, but I need the third one, Blinn-Phong)
I've read [somewhere](https://developer.blender.org/T34564) that the Blender CookTorr reflection model is actually the Blinn-Phong model but I could not understand how to set the specular exponent (shiny) of the Bilnn-Phong model using CookTorr input parameters (Hardness maybe?)

Since I am new in using Blender, I want to know is there any possibility to define Blinn-Phong reflection model as a user defined reflection model? 
If yes, should I use Blender "Node Editor" to define a new material?

Has anyone done this before? (Blinn-Phong is a well-known reflection model, isn't it?)

If yes, it would be appreciated to let me have a look :-) 

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question but this may help someone.
[image: Phong model with a Blinn Phong Specular]

This is the Phong model I made (thanks to this [tut](https://youtu.be/XQdIxkd54X4)) with a Blinn Phong Specular.

Down below are the preview:

Phong Sqecular:
[image: Phong Sqecular]

Blinn Phong Sqecular:
[image: Blinn Phong Sqecular]

Answer (score -4):

Q. I want to know is there any possibility to define Blinn-Phong reflection model as a user defined reflection model?

A. Yes

Q.If yes, should I use Blender "Node Editor" to define a new material?

A. Yes

Q. Has anyone done this before?

A. Yes, quite so.

I will try not to write a 2718 page treatise here.  Cycles render engine is designed as a photo realistic (PR) physics based renderer. Blender render is a respectable renderer different than cycles.  I am trying to give you some terms for further research.  Your public library probably has electronic titles on Cycles and there is the general internet and there are just a few video tutorials on video websites.

If we look at the node system for Cycles we are delivered fragments with geometric surface normal information, camera information and more.  Vector operations resulting in scalars such as dot product are available and are quite relevant to shading.  So you have the freedom to write original or not so original shaders.  Your results can be physics based or artistically styled.  Many relevant math functions are available such as sine, cosine, modulus. Your image is as unlimited as your creativity.

Know that dot product and vector product are your BFF when shading.  Just remember to get some sleep once in a while.  Try to take breaks every 8 hours of writing material nodes.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question very well as this just seems to say "Yes, this is possible" as opposed to actually describing *how* to achieve the specific desired result.

Comment: His question did not request the mathematical formulae for a specific reflection model.  He can change his request to specifically request that.  I answered the questions with question marks (?).  You have the power to also either add that phantom question to his writing or ask him to change his original post.  Feel free to give me a demerit.  I genuinely assumed if he mentioned a specific reflection model he has seen the mathematics somewhere else.   He did not ask for a finished node diagram.  Perhaps he wants that learning experience for personal growth.  I bow to your mind reading talents.

Comment: @RayMairlot ... Please see above.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger,
Many thanks, 
Your answer is obviously useful, but you're right, I had to ask the fourth question:
Where can I find this user defined Blinn-Phong Reflection Model?

Comment: You may modify your original post for all to see.